# How to interpret R contrasts when given continuous and categorical explanatory variables?

Tags: r, regression, contrasts

Let's say I have run a linear regression model that models the sugar content in a Jelly Bean as a function of its colour and weight:

`lm(sugar ~ color + weight)`

The summary of the above model outputs the following:

```
Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)    0.07934    0.28625   0.277   0.7823
   coloured    0.41976    0.09952   2.208   0.0296 *
     weight    2.54078    0.35643   7.128 1.81e-10 ***
```

What is the mean sugar content of a coloured Jelly Bean?

Would it be 0.07934 + 0.41976 + 2.54078? Or is it not possible to calculate without knowing the mean weight of a coloured Jelly Bean?

I would be very grateful for any help with this. Please note this is not a homework question.

Comment: To answer this question you would need to know the coding of the coloured variable. I’m guessing that it should have been coded as a factor classed variable and was not.

Comment: How many different colors? If only two, colored/uncolored, it does not matter if you code as a factor or as numerically zero/one, but tell us the coding

Comment: See my answer at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/602431/919 for a detailed explanation of how to find out *for sure* what your parameter estimates mean.  We must be a little uncertain about your question, though, because your output doesn't match the code you claim produced it: the latter refers to `color` while the former refers to `coloured`.  BTW, where is there any "contrast" in this question?

Answer (score 1):

Is difficult to decide without knowing what type of variables are involved. I suppose according to the output, that the coloured is dummy variable (TRUE/FALSE). The easiest way is to fit it into the equation of linear regression:

$$
\begin{align*}
    Y_i &= \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{1,i} + \beta_2 x_{2,i}  + \epsilon_i = \\
    &= 0.07934 + 0.41976 \cdot \mathbb{I}\{color_i = `colored` \} + 2.54078 \cdot weight_i + \epsilon_i
\end{align*}
$$

and insert the necessary variables (weight, is colored). If you don't know if it is a colour pack, the result always refers to the non-coloured package. Non-coloured is reference level, and is included in intercept (beta0).

Comment: Cross Validated is MathJax enabled. So you can type the equation in LaTeX (you seem to already have done so) and make it easier to read. Here are some [resources](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1604/237901).

Comment: @dipetkov thanks for your insight. I have commented in StackExchange for the first time. In Stackoverflow that's impossible, isn't it?

Comment: No, StackOverflow doesn't support MathJax. See [Which Stack Exchange sites use MathJax?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216606/477872).