# linear regression in R: contr.treatment vs contr.sum

Tags: r, regression, linear-model, contrasts, lm

Following are two linear regression models with the same predictors and response variable, but with different contrast coding methods. In the first model, the contrast coding method is "contr.treatment" and in the second model, it is "contr.sum".

```
options(contrasts = c("contr.treatment","contr.poly"))
model1<-lm(RISKINESS~1+GENDER + `SUBSTANCE USE`, data = df)
```

```
summary(model1)


Call:
lm(formula = RISKINESS ~ 1 + GENDER + `SUBSTANCE USE`, data = df)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-1.250 -1.000 -0.225  0.800  2.000 

Coefficients:
                              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                    15.4500     1.1773  13.123 4.62e-08 ***
GENDERM                         3.7500     1.0461   3.585 0.004283 ** 
`SUBSTANCE USE`no_use         -12.4500     1.3684  -9.098 1.88e-06 ***
`SUBSTANCE USE`once_per_month  -6.4500     1.4545  -4.434 0.001004 ** 
`SUBSTANCE USE`once_per_week   -3.9500     0.8103  -4.875 0.000491 ***
```

```
options(contrasts = c("contr.sum","contr.poly"))
model2<-lm(RISKINESS~1+GENDER + `SUBSTANCE USE`, data = df)
```

```
summary(model2)

Call:
lm(formula = RISKINESS ~ 1 + GENDER + `SUBSTANCE USE`, data = df)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-1.250 -1.000 -0.225  0.800  2.000 

Coefficients:
                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)       11.6125     0.3421  33.945 1.74e-12 ***
GENDER1           -1.8750     0.5230  -3.585  0.00428 ** 
`SUBSTANCE USE`1   5.7125     0.7923   7.210 1.73e-05 ***
`SUBSTANCE USE`2  -6.7375     0.7366  -9.147 1.79e-06 ***
`SUBSTANCE USE`3  -0.7375     0.8150  -0.905  0.38489
```

The results of the coefficient estimates, standard errors, and t-values are not the same.

How the results in the contrast sum calculated?
Which method should be used (guidelines and references are well accepted)?

Comment: To know *exactly* and authoritatively what your software is doing, [inspect the model matrix](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/602431/919).

Comment: The model is the same but the different contrasts are comparing different things:
One compares a treatment against a reference. The other compares against the average.
https://rpubs.com/monajhzhu/608609